# Is $\int_{x}^{\infty}{\frac{f(t)}{t}dt}\in L^1(I)$ when $f\in L^1{(I)}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $I=\mathbb{R^+}$, suppose we have $f\in L^1{(I)}$, can we obtain that $$\int_{x}^{\infty}{\frac{f(t)}{t}dt}\in L^1(I) ~?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: interchange the order of integration in
$$\int_0^\infty \int_x^\infty \dfrac{|f(t)|}{t}\ dt\ dx$$